# ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.2:prepare Unable to check for local modifications

Tags: maven

**

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.2:prepare (default-cli) on project artifactorydemo: Unable to check for local modifications
ERROR] Provider message:
ERROR] The svn command failed.
ERROR] Command output:
ERROR] svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
ERROR] svn: E155036: The working copy at 'E:\STS\New folder\artifactorydemo'
ERROR] is too old (format 29) to work with client version '1.9.1 (r1698128)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.
ERROR] -> [Help 1]
ERROR]
```

**

Please suggest some thing am not figure outing thid where am doing the wrong 
Thanks in advance

Comment: he i got solution it is now working for me

Answer (score 0):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.artifactory.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactorydemo</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>artifactorydemo</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>

      <scm>
             <connection>scm:svn:https://Subbareddy-PC/svn/jenkins/trunk/artifactorydemo</connection>
             <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://Subbareddy-PC/svn/jenkins/trunk/artifactorydemo</developerConnection>
             <url>https://Subbareddy-PC/svn/jenkins/trunk/artifactorydemo</url>
      </scm>

        <build>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <preparationGoals>clean verify install</preparationGoals>
                    <tagBase>https://Subbareddy-PC/svn/jenkins/tags</tagBase>

                    <!--<checkModificationExcludes>
                            <checkModificationExclude>pom.xml</checkModificationExclude>
                    </checkModificationExcludes>-->
                    <providerImplementations>
                      <svn>javasvn</svn>
                    </providerImplementations>
                </configuration>
              <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                      <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                      <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                      <version>2.0.6</version>
                      <scope>compile</scope>
                    </dependency>
                  </dependencies>
            </plugin>

          </plugins>
        </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>Subbareddy-PC-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```